# How to get control of canvas lines shown in Dygraph?

Tags: charts, dygraphs

I want to take the control of Canvas lines of Dygraph similar to that of highcharts. To get an idea please check the following jsfiddle.

Reference: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + 
 this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 },

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 
194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
});
```

Comment: Does "get control" mean "attach a click  handler?"

Comment: Yes when i click on the lines of the graph i should get the click event display alert and later i can play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [`pointClickCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#pointClickCallback) option that you can set. See the [callback demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/callback.html) for an example. Note that this will catch clicks on points but not the lines connecting them.

Comment: Thanks that helps is there anything that catches lines connecting them?

Comment: Not that's built into dygraphs, sorry.